# Update Combobox according to co-ordinate in a GridCell

Tags: c#

I attached a **combobox** in a **GridViewCell** with **combox.Location property**.But,I have mutiple combobox.While updating combox item/value,Changed selected item is not seen in the GridCell.How can I update the combo according to Location?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please relate something writing your code. What tool you are using? ASP.NET/C#??

Comment: the combobox is not contaning the changed item as selected for multiple combobox

Answer (score 0):

You can find the combobox with it's location this way:

```
ComboBox tempCombo = (ComboBox)This.Controls.Find("YourComboBoxName",True)[0];
```

Then you can refer to tempCombo and refill it.

Comment: combobox is generated in every row of specific location of a gridviewcell.My combox is just pasted by finding gridcell location.for multiple combobox, at changing time,its showing previous item.how i can get the changed item to be selected in the combobox?

Comment: I do not get what you mean, if you could give us an example it would be better

Comment: Like,I have five combobox in five rows of a grid.1 have 2 element in combobox.After changing the 1st combobox items,i change the items of 2nd combobox,but,i see that 1st combobox lost its changed item,it is showing previous item.Am i able to take you to my prob?

Comment: cmbBranchcode.ValueMember= _ds.Tables[0].Columns["cmbBranchID"].ToString();
 cmbBranchcode.Location = dgvCDBLClientProfile.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, dgvCDBLClientProfile.CurrentRow.Index, true).Location;
cmbBranchcode.SelectedValue = cmbCurrentVal;cmbBranchcode.Show();